# Unity 3D - Moving Object & Player with Push/Pull || Applying Opposing Force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

so I've been struggling with a problem for a while, not sure how to approach it.

I'm trying to simulate a magic system similar to The Force used in Star Wars in Unity, and have ran into some troubles. I'm trying to simulate pushing and pulling on objects appropriately. This means that when the player pushes an object, both the player and the object get a force applied to them. If the object is light enough, the player shouldn't be affected in any noticeable way, and the object should be pushed away. If their masses are similar, both should be pushed away at some rate, and if the object is heaver, the player should be mainly pushed away. The same goes with pulling. The problem is when objects are anchored against something. If a player pushes a light object into a wall, the player should start receiving enough force to start pushing them backwards, since the combined mass of the wall and the object are pushing the player back.

Currently, I'm able to do the first part with the following code when a key is pressed:
Note that the force is determined based off the distance from the player to the object and the mass of them.

```
// dir: push or pull (-1 or 1)

Vector3 directionToPlayer = (dir * (player.transform.position - transform.position)).normalized;

rb.AddRelativeForce(directionToPlayer * f * Time.deltaTime);

player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(-directionToPlayer * f * Time.deltaTime);
```

As it is, the code works fine when the objects are just by themselves just by relying on Unity's Physics system. However, it does NOT work when an object is being pushed against a wall, or something really heavy. This is pretty clear as I'm just applying the same force to both the object and the player, and letting Unity decide whether to move the entity based off its rigidbody mass.

My question is, how can I detect if an object is anchored, and if it is combine the mass of the object and the object which it is anchored to, and apply that force to the player? I was thinking how to do this, and I know that I need to figure out the direction of which the force is being applied from, and then determine whether the object that's being pushed or pulled is colliding with anything in that direction, and if so apply a force to the player based off the combined masses. This gets a little tricky however when pushing an object at an angle that's against a wall. For example consider the following scenario:

[image]

There is both a horizontal and a vertical component of the force being applied on the cube, and so that should be considered when the cube+wall combined object pushes back on the player. How could this be accomplished or approached? I'm really struggling coming up with how to do this without hard coding direcitons.

Any help is appreciated, and I'll gladly clarify if anything is unclear.

*NOTE* The system is really based from a book series called Mistborn, but the concept is really close to The Force in Star Wars, and so I'll run with that as more people are familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution, but you can use my idea below to acquire the nearby objects and then apply force to your objects and player in accordance with that.

The script should be placed on the object you are pushing or at least use a sphere collider from the object you are pushing.

```
public List<string> _ValidTargetTags = new List<string> { "Wall" };

public void CheckNearbyArea()
{
    //Each of the nearby items will be checked to see if they are a wall or other valid target.
    Collider[] ObjectsStruck = ScanForItems(GetComponent<SphereCollider>());
    foreach (var o in ObjectsStruck)
    {
        if (_ValidTargetTags.Contains(o.gameObject.tag))
        {
            //If wall or other valid target
            //Check where wall is placed
            //Act according to wall position.
        }
    }
}

///The method below should find a list of all items inside a spherecollider of the object you are pushing.
Collider[] ScanForItems(SphereCollider sphereCollider)
{
    Vector3 center = sphereCollider.transform.position + sphereCollider.center;
    float radius = sphereCollider.radius;

    Collider[] allOverlappingColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius);

    return allOverlappingColliders;
}
```

With this solution you will be able to check the players location relative to any nearby walls. This you can use to calculate what his direction is compared to the wall, relative to the object he is pushing.